# ClientFunction from function file isn't executing when calling it in my script

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I created a function in my function file so I could just call it in my scripts. What's different about this one from my other functions is that it's a ClientFunction within a regular function. Calling it in my script file doesn't do anything.

I've created my function and imported and exported everything I've needed to. I am calling the function in my script the same way I call the rest of my other functions. Those other functions are working just fine.

From my function file 'globalFunctions.js'

```
import {ClientFunction} from 'testcafe';

export async function scroll(){
  const scroll = ClientFunction(function() {
    window.scrollBy(0,1000)
});
  return(scroll);
};
```

From my script file

```
import * as globalFunctions from './global_functions.js';
globalFunctions.scroll(t)
```

Other function I'm calling that works just fine

```
globalFunctions.namegenerator(t)
```

Expected:

When I call the function scroll(), the page should scroll to the bottom of the page.

Actual:

The page does not scroll down, the code goes to the next line, and then the script fails to say my object isn't found.

Answer (score 4):

I got this to work by changing my function to:

```
export const scroll = ClientFunction(function() {
    return window.scrollBy(0,1000)
});
```

And call it in my script via:

```
await globalFunctions.scroll()
```